# React passing parameters to routes not in the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, express

Take our list of products for sale

```js
     {data.map(x => {
           return(
                 <Col _id={x._id} name={x.name} key={x._id}
                 className={`${styles.starter_col}`} onClick={navigateTo} />
               );
     })}
```

We click on a product with name attribute `Starter-1`

```js
    const navigateTo = (e) => {
        const nameParam = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name");
        navigate(`/starter/${nameParam}`);
    }
```

It routes to `/starter/Starter-1`

```js
      {
        path: "/starter/:itemName",
        element: <StarterEntry />,
        loader: async ({ params }) => {
          return StoreItemLoader(params.itemName);
        }
      }
```

Using this loader

```js
const StoreItemLoader = async (itemName) => {
  const data = await axios.get(`/queryproducts/${itemName}`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.product);
    return res.data.product;
  });
  return data;
}
```

I want to maintain the nice url of `starter/Starter-1`, meaning no url parameters. Starter-1's url will therefore be persistent, but the contents of the product (components, price etc) may change in the future. So for this reason, I need to pass the id as I can create new entries in the db and they will have unique IDS, whereas the name `Starter-1` will not be unique. A map containing this translation from `Starter-1` to `someObjectId123` on the server or client side is an option (in my head).

This is the most ideal situation as it avoids me having to update one record/entry in the db and somehow invalidating data on the fly on the client side (thinking of the scenario where the user is checking out with their cached version of a product, but the order then reflects the newest updated item and there would be no record of the older item on my end)